# Chromium dev tools Resource preview icons shown as broken images under Network tab

Tags: icons, resources, google-chrome-devtools, preview

We are currently working on linux based chromium version 85.0.4183.93. When we use dev tools for debugging we observed that resource preview icons for script files, css files, document files and font files under Network tab are getting displayed as broken images. This was not observed in earlier versions of chrome.

Any inputs regarding debugging this or any clue would be helpful

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools.

Comment: We are debugging Chromium 85 debug target using chrome Version 103.0.5060.134.